# Error when appending to an empty list in python

Tags: python, append

I get:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I want to start with an empty list:

Edate = []

But Q1) how do I define this to be a list that will take in dates?

Im not sure, so I input a timstamp to get me started:

```
Edate = [Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

which is now a 1 element list

Now, I want to append dates:

```
dates=

 1    2018-01-29
 2    2017-10-11
 3    2017-03-28
 4    2016-10-25
 5    2016-03-02
 6    2015-11-04
 7    2015-10-22
 8    2014-01-24
 9    2014-01-03
 10   2013-10-09
```

But in trying to do so, I encounter the aforementioned error, which I don't understand. Thanks

PS- I would also like to do the same for numbers:

```
entrynumbers = []

data=


0        NaN
1    -31.336
2    -36.012
3    -21.282
4    -41.859
5    -31.381
6    -30.789
7    -27.509

entrynumbers = entrynumbers.append(data)
```

Comment: You don't have an empty list. You have `None`, which is not a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
entrynumbers = entrynumbers.append(data)
```

`list.append` mutates the list it is called on, but returns `None`. So do not reassign, just do:

```
entrynumbers.append(data)
```

For Q1, Python `list` is not parametrized like collection types in other languages. Even if you add an intial `TimeStamp` object, you will still be able to add objects of any other type later on.

Comment: I had missed that line, good catch.